# Laravel i can't show only user-created objects checking by user_email, like a shopping cart different for every user

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, phpmyadmin, controller

I'm trying to create a particular online address book where each user can register and create his contacts.

When the contacts are created, the "user_email" and "session_id" of the user who created it are saved in "students" tab.

[This is the structure of the users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJbKT.png)

[This is the structure of the students table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bpWo.png)

This is the function "addStudent" present in "StudetsController" (Don't pay attention to "ICF Dropdown")

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Student;
use App\Product;
use Session;
use User;
use Auth;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use function GuzzleHttp\Promise\all;

class StudentsController extends Controller
{

public function addStudent(Request $request){
        if($request->isMethod('post')){
            $data = $request->all();
            $student = new Student();
            $student->student_sex = $data['student_sex'];
            $student->student_name = $data['student_name'];
            $student->student_surname = $data['student_surname'];
            $student->student_birth = $data['student_birth'];
            $student->codice_icf = $data['codice_icf'];
            if(!empty($data['description'])){
                $student->description = $data['description'];
            }else{
                $student->description = '';
            }
            $student->user_email = $data['user_email']=Auth::user()->email;
            if(empty($session_id)) {
                $student->session_id = $data['session_id']= str_random(40);
            }else{
                $student->session_id = Student::get('session_id');
            }
            $student->save();
            return redirect('/')->with('flash_message_success','Lo studente è stato creato con successo!');
        }

        //ICF drop down start
        $products = Product::get();
        $products_dropdown = "<option selected disabled>Codice ICF</option>";
        foreach($products as $pro){
            $products_dropdown .= "<option value='".$pro->product_name."'>".$pro->product_name."</option>";
        }
        //Categories drop down ends

        return view('students.add_student')->with(compact('products_dropdown'));
    }
```

[As you can see the students are created and they save the email of who created them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nBLE.png)

Now on the index page, i would like the logged in user to see only his students.

First of all i create a foreach loop for students in index.blade.php

```
@foreach($students as $student)
                <!-- Item -->
                <div class="item">
                    <!-- Images -->
                    @if($student->student_sex == "M")
                    <img class="img-holder" src="{{asset('images/frontend_images/studente-M.jpg')}}" alt="" >
                    @else
                        <img class="img-holder" src="{{asset('images/frontend_images/studente-F.jpg')}}" alt="" >
                    @endif
                    <!-- Overlay  -->
                    <!-- Item Name -->
                    <div class="item-name"> <a href="#.">{{$student->student_name}} {{$student->student_surname}}</a>
                        <p>{{$student->codice_icf}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

Where "$students" is defined in "IndexController" like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use App\Product;
use App\Student;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class IndexController extends Controller
{


    public function index(){
        $students = Student::get();
        return view('index')->with(compact('students'));
    }
}
```

And the $student function in "StudentsController" like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Student;
use App\Product;
use Session;
use User;
use Auth;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use function GuzzleHttp\Promise\all;

class StudentsController extends Controller
{

 public function addStudent(Request $request){...}

 public function student(){
        if(Auth::check()){
            $user_email = Auth::user()->email;
            $students = DB::table('students')->where(['user_email'=>$user_email])->get();
        }
        return redirect('/')->with(compact('students'));
    }
```

[As you can see the students appear on the index page, but if i log in with a different user they stay the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaYU4.png)

This is my users controller, if you need the login function

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use App\Student;
use Session;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function userRegister(){
        return view('users.register');
    }

    public function userLogin(){
        return view('users.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request){
        if($request->isMethod('post')){
            $data = $request->all();
            if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$data['email'],'password'=>$data['password']])){
                $userStatus = User::where('email',$data['email'])->first();
                if($userStatus->status == 0){
                    return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_error', 'Il tuo  account non è attivo! Conferma la tua email per attivarlo.');
                }
                Session::put('frontSession',$data['email']);
                return redirect('/');
            }else{
                return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_error', 'Email o Password errate!');
            }
        }
    }

    public function register(Request $request){
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $data = $request->all();
            //Check if User Already exist
            $usersCount = User::where('email', $data['email'])->count();
            if ($usersCount > 0) {
                return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_error', 'Email già registrata!');
            } else {
                $user = new User;
                $user->name = $data['name'];
                $user->email = $data['email'];
                $user->password = bcrypt($data['password']);
                $user->save();

                // Send Confirmation Email
                $email = $data['email'];
                $messageData = ['email' => $data['email'],'name'=>$data['name'],'code'=>base64_encode($data['email'])];
                Mail::send('emails.confirmation',$messageData, function ($message) use($email){
                    $message->to($email)->subject('Conferma Account');
                });

                return redirect('/login')->with('flash_message_success', 'Perfavore conferma la tua email per attivare il tuo account!');

            }
        }
    }

    public function logout(){
        Auth::logout();
        Session::forget('frontSession');
        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function confirmAccount($email){
        $email = base64_decode($email);
        $userCount = User::where('email', $email)->count();
        if ($userCount > 0) {
            $userDetails = User::where('email', $email)->first();
            if ($userDetails->status == 1) {
                return redirect('/login')->with('flash_message_success', 'Il tuo account è già attivo! Effettua il login.');
            } else {
                User::where('email', $email)->update(['status' => 1]);
                //Welcome Email
                $messageData = ['email' => $email,'name'=>$userDetails->name];
                Mail::send('emails.welcome',$messageData, function ($message) use($email){
                    $message->to($email)->subject('Benvenuto!');
                });
                return redirect('/login')->with('flash_message_success', 'Il tuo account è stato attivato! Effettua il login adesso.');
            }
        }else{
            abort(404);
        }
    }

    public function checkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $usersCount = User::where('email', $data['email'])->count();
        if ($usersCount > 0) {
            echo "false";
        } else {
            echo "true"; die;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I see for each different user only the students created by him using his email as a control field?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are doing a redirect to your IndexController

```php
return redirect('/')->with(compact('students'));
```

You cannot redirect and pass some variable

Comment: Ok thanks, i corrected the line in question, but i still see all the students created and not just those related to the email of the logged in user

Comment: Based on the code, you see all students because the page is served by `IndexController`, not by `StudentsController` (where you filter by email)

Comment: Thank you so much i understand, now i create an answer with the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **[Oleg Andreyev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1205171/oleg-andreyev)** advice, i solved the problem by removing the function "student" in "StudentsController", so i delete this line:

```
 public function student(){
    if(Auth::check()){
        $user_email = Auth::user()->email;
        $students = DB::table('students')->where(['user_email'=>$user_email])->get();
    }
    return redirect('/')->with(compact('students'));
}
```

And i changed the "index" function to "IndexController" from this:

```
public function index(){
    $students = Student::get();
    return view('index')->with(compact('students'));
}
```

To this one:

```
public function index(){
    $students = Student::get();
    if(Auth::check()){
        $user_email = Auth::user()->email;
        $students = DB::table('students')->where(['user_email'=>$user_email])->get();
    }
    return view('index')->with(compact('students'));
}
```

And now i can see the students related to the email of the user who created them!